# change of variables question for random variables

Tags: probability

If $Y$ is a transformation of $X$, then why is it that $|f_X(x) dx| = |f_Y(y) dy|$ instead of simply $f_X(x) dx = f_Y(y) dy$?  This should be an intuitively easy question but I'm trying to think of an example for when this would be the case.  Is it because $dy$ could "intuitively" be negative?  For example, the mapping from $X$ to $-X.$

I just need some clarification here.  Thanks!

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables

Comment: Sorry but the question has no meaning whatsoever. You could begin by defining the quite odd notion of $|dx|$. And, since $|\ |$ is usually applied to real numbers or to complex numbers, by defining the object $dx$... Seriously, you might google *change of variables*, don't you think?

Comment: Change of variables in 1D (i.e., single variables) are sometimes done with a negative derivative (and thereby integrating the "wrong"-way round, i.e., from large to low values in the integration region). Multivariable change of variable necessarily involves the absolute value of the Jacobian.

Comment: The $| |$ notation was used in a wikipedia article on the topic --- I just wanted to make sure I was understanding it properly.  The $|dx|$ thrown in the article threw me off a little bit as well.

And also it's a lot more efficient to ask here than to google several different sources.

Thanks Fabian!